# How to create a custom function that finds if a date in pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas, function

I am trying to create a function that takes in a date and returns yes if it exists in a column called date which is a datetime column. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

e.g of dataframe

```
       date       orders
801   2016-08-01    123
1352  2016-08-02    456
433   2016-08-03    789
509   2016-08-04    999

def weekoforders(date):
    if date in df['date']:
        print('yes')
    else:
        print('no')

weekoforders('2016-08-07')
```

Comment: `in` against a `pd.Series` looks at the *index* not the values themselves (if you think a series as a dict formed that way with indices being the "keys"), so you can change your `if` to `if date in df.date.to_numpy()` and it'll check against values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `date` column is already in **datetime format**, you can use:

```
def weekoforders(date):
    if df['date'].isin([pd.Timestamp(date)]).any():
        print('yes')
    else:
        print('no')
```

or:

```
def weekoforders(date):
    if pd.Timestamp(date) in df['date'].values:
        print('yes')
    else:
        print('no')
```

If your `date` column is in **string format**, use:

```
def weekoforders(date):
    if df['date'].isin([date]).any():
        print('yes')
    else:
        print('no')
```

or:

```
def weekoforders(date):
    if date in df['date'].values:
        print('yes')
    else:
        print('no')
```

**Result**:

```
weekoforders('2016-08-02')

yes


weekoforders('2016-08-07')

no
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> df
        Date
0 2021-01-01
1 2021-01-05
2 2021-01-09
3 2021-01-13
4 2021-01-17
5 2021-01-21
6 2021-01-25
7 2021-01-29
```

```
def weekoforders(date):
    return 'yes' if df['Date'].eq(date).any() else 'no'
```

```
>>> weekoforders('2021-01-25')
'yes'

>>> weekoforders('2021-01-19')
'no'
```